# I am new at android dev and I tried to install flutter but getting this error. What to do next?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWtCQ.png)C:\Users\KIIT>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.804], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
X android-studio-dir = 'C:\Program
X Android Studio not found at 'C:\Program
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: Can you still open Android Studio?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381649/android-studio-4-1-0-flutter-and-dart-plugin-not-installed

Answer (score 0):

In android studio settings>plugin search for flutter plugin and dart plugin install both of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:** First, you need to install Dart Sdk
Reference: https://dart.dev/get-dart
To install the Dart SDK:

```
 choco install dart-sdk
```

To upgrade the Dart SDK:

```
 choco upgrade dart-sdk
```

**Step-2:** Then install the latest Flutter SDK
Reference: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
```

**Step-3:** Now Open Android Studio and check for Plugin updates

[image: Flutter Plugin Update]

**Step-4:**Restart Android Studio and open New Project.
Now you will see Options

[image: New Project Options]

**Step-5:** Run `flutter doctor` again:
Now you will get output like

[image]

Now you are ready to go....